# How can I develope a water loop cooler system sustaining with liquid nitrogen?

Tags: cooling, experimental-physics, air, cryogenics

Water will be circulated in the water pipe and liquid nitrogen tanks heat going to cool the water pipe,by the way to the water too. And fan is going to blow this cold air and heat is going to be decreased. Is it possible ?

Comment: This is much too broad of a question to be answered in the site's Q&A format.

Comment: liquid nitrogen is only cold when it is boiling,

Comment: The nitrogen is very likely to freeze the water , very fast.